# Rust file returns wrong values

Tags: rust

I am trying to read a very simple file into a vector.

```
fn read_file(file_name: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut file = File::open(file_name).unwrap();
    let mut contents = Vec::new();
    //read file into the vec
    for i in 0..file.read_to_end(&mut contents).unwrap() {
        contents.push(i as u8);
    }
    contents
}
```

And my file is this:

```
5
10
15
4
8
2
```

But interestingly, when I read the file and print the contents, I get:

```
[53, 13, 10, 49, 48, 13, 10, 49, 53, 13, 10, 52, 13, 10, 56, 13, 10, 50, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

Obviously, I am doing something wrong, but my question actually is, where did Rust find all of these values?

Answer (score 4):

The numbers are the bytes of your file.

```
53 = b'5'
13 = b'\r'
10 = b'\n'
49 = b'1'
48 = b'0'
...
```

If you want the actual numbers you'd have to parse the file into lines and the lines into
numbers. Something like this should do that:

```rust
use std::io::{BufReader,BufRead};
fn read_file(file_name: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    let file = File::open(file_name).unwrap();
    let bufread = BufReader::new(file);
    bufread.lines().map(|x| {
        x
            .unwrap_or_default()
            .parse::<u8>()
            .unwrap_or_default()
    }).collect()
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, so read returns bytes? I didn't know that

Comment: OP is then also pushing every number up to the number of bytes read into the buffer, I can't imagine that that's intentional either.

Comment: @merovingian It doesn't return bytes, it _reads_ bytes into the buffer you pass it. It returns a result containing either an error or the number of bytes that were read.

Comment: I feel like this is too much work for just for reading a file into a vector

Comment: Well it's [only plaintext](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd5uJ7Nlvvo) you're dealing with.